# How to use PyCharm Remote Deployment to develop multiple packages?

Tags: python, deployment, pycharm, package, remote-debugging

PyCharm Professional has a Remote Deployment feature that allows for editing, running and debugging code remotely. This is a powerful feature when writing short scripts and top-level applications that make use of standard or third-party library packages. You can even create a virtualenv on the remote, with all dependency packages installed, and use that to execute the remote program.

However when writing applications that make use of multiple packages that are also developed alongside the application, it becomes necessary to edit packages. Without PyCharm the usual way to do this is with `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py develop`, which integrates the source directory with Python's package system, making it possible to edit a number of packages alongside the application.

With a *single* package, I've found the PyCharm will deploy the package code into its remote workspace, which works OK for debugging if I'm running a script or entry point from within this *same* package.

The problem I'm having with PyCharm is that it's not clear how to remotely edit and debug *multiple* packages. Let's say I have a PyCharm project open for one of these packages. When finding references or debugging into code that is in another (yet still developed-by-me) package, PyCharm shows a cached version of the second package (on my local machine). This is fine until I edit the second package on the remote host - after which the cached version is now out of sync and doesn't automatically update. This leads to a mismatch between execution result and debugger/editor state.

There are other quirks too, such as the edited package not actually being installed into the remote's virtualenv.

I haven't been able to find a proper guide to this workflow in PyCharm's documentation, and I'm starting to wonder if I'm either going about this the entirely wrong way, or maybe PyCharm just doesn't support this kind of app+multiple-packages development?

Comment: So I came back to this problem a few months later, and google came up with some relevant questions on the topic. Problem is, they are all mine, and all are unanswered. Looks like it can't be done.